# K-theory of projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, coherent-sheaves, algebraic-k-theory

Is there any way to prove that the twisting sheaves $\mathcal{O}(K)$ generate the algebraic K-theory of projective space without actually using any K-theory machinery (e.g. Bott periodicity)? Like for example, just being able to write down a resolution by powers of twisting sheaves. I know that arbitrary coherent sheaves on projective space are hard to get a handle of, so it might not be possible, but it would be helpful.

Comment: See Hilbert syzygy theorem

Comment: Oh! $\sim$ is actually an exact functor. I had actually thought about that, but had it drilled into my head that "proj is not functorial" so thought it couldn't work. Thanks!

Comment: I think there's some subtlety I'm missing here, though - we need a free resolution in the category of *graded* modules. But now I see that many references state the syzygy theorem with graded modules to begin with - weird, I had only ever seen the affine version.